# Angular bind variable from controller to view inside html

Tags: angularjs, view, binding, controller

Need to bind variable from controller to view:

In Index html:

```
<body ng-app="widget" ng-controller="WidgetCtrl">

    <div ng-view class="chatWidget"></div>

</body>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.showHideSchedule = true;
```

In view:

```
<div ng-show="WidgetCtrl.showHideSchedule">{{WidgetCtrl.showHideSchedule}}</div>
```

WidgetCtrl.showHideSchedule - doesn't works

Comment: It should be `ng-show="showHideSchedule"`

Comment: could you please add a plunkr/fiddle of problem.?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an alias for controller like

```
<body ng-app="widget" ng-controller="WidgetCtrl as wg">
    <div ng-view class="chatWidget"></div>
</body>



<div ng-show="wg.showHideSchedule">{{wg.showHideSchedule}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-view` like you are.  I would set up the html body like this

```
<body ng-app="widget" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

   <div ng-view class="chatWidget"></div>

</body>
```

Then I would set the widget.html file like this

```
<div ng-show="widget.showHideSchedule">{{widget.widgetName}}</div>
```

Then your js code should look something like this in order to use that `widget` alias

```
  .controller('WidgetCtrl', 
    function() {
      this.showHideSchedule = true;
      this.widgetName = 'new widget';
  }])
```

Here is a plunker of this

https://plnkr.co/edit/l6lmAByRXm3dYfHIrARX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It works by me with help of $scope.$broadcast event. I am not sure is it a best solution, but it works.